# How do I delete similar dictionaries from the list and get a single value?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am trying to detect "User Name" data that are similar to each other in the list and delete all similar ones except the last directory from the list. But I Cannot Delete. How can I do that?

```
            a = [{'level': '46', 'Kullanıcı Adı': '  .', 'Mesaj': 'jgfkslkjghfdkskhjnfdsfhkjn'}, 
            {'level': '46', 'Kullanıcı Adı': 'KTeX', 'Mesaj': 'Ya jager ndkslsjfodldke'}, 
            {'level': '70', 'Kullanıcı Adı': 'Emnvdar', 'Mesaj': ' ahahahfdjggsgd'}, 
            {'level': '54', 'Kullanıcı Adı': 'Emnvdar', 'Mesaj': 'afdsfadsfdsfdsfds'}, 
            {'level': '52', 'Kullanıcı Adı': 'Lylz', 'Mesaj': 'hüptürük'}, 
            {'level': '59', 'Kullanıcı Adı': 'Emnvdar', 'Mesaj': 'jıljkdfvbfdjfdffdblkdbnfd'}, 
            {'level': '61', 'Kullanıcı Adı': 'Lylz', 'Mesaj': 'mert efsane ya'}, 
            {'level': '59', 'Kullanıcı Adı': 'Emnvdar', 'Mesaj': 'ahhqhaha'}]



          

            countest = []
            name = []

            for i in list(range(len(a)))[::-1]:
                veri = (a[i]['Kullanıcı Adı'],i)
                name.append(veri)
                C = Counter(name)
                Union = [[k,]*v for k,v in C.items()] 
                

            print(name,"name")

            print(name[0])
            otherlist= list(range(len(name)))[::-1]

            for i in otherlist:
                print(name[i][0],name[i][1])
```

Comment: What are you doing to delete?

Comment: Is your problem to find similar names or to delete the found dictionaries?

Comment: Yes. true. to leave a unique value in the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is probably to use an ordered dictionary to rebuild the list. Python 3.6+ has ordered `dict` implementation, so replace `OrderedDict` with `dict` below. For older python versions, use `collections.OrderedDict` as shown:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

b = list(OrderedDict((d['Kullanıcı Adı'], d) for d in a).values())
```

You can create a dictionary from an iterable containing `(key, value)` pairs. The last mapping for repeating keys is always used. That's what `OrderedDict((d['Kullanıcı Adı'], d) for d in a)` does. The order of the values returned by `values()` will match that of the keys, so you can just extract right back into a `list`.

The problem with this approach, despite its relative simplicity, is that the keys will be ordered by their first appearance, even though values will be taken from the last. For example:

```
>>> list(OrderedDict([('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('a', 3)]).values())
[3, 2]  # expected 2, 3
```

If that's a problem, you can iterate through the original list backwards, checking if you've already encountered a key, and then reverse the result:

```
od = OrderedDict()
for d in reversed(a):
    if d['Kullanıcı Adı'] not in od:
        od[d['Kullanıcı Adı']] = d
a = list(reversed(od.values()))
```

Comment: thank you so much. I'm working on it right now and coming back

Comment: sorry i guess i have to learn more to solve it. You probably solved the problem. However, I cannot solve it because my knowledge is not enough. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @sabcan try just running my code. If you have the original list `a` and `from collections import OrderedDict`, you can just copy and paste the code.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll study the OrderedDict topic further. I solved the problem.

Comment: @sabcan. Glad you got it working. If you're using a version of python after 3.6, you can use normal `dict` instead of `OrderedDict`. I posted that way because it's guaranteed to work even on old versions.

Comment: I saw you edit the answer.I understand much better now.hank you very much.:)